# How to update particular data in dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server

My scenario is I've two grids and based on Grid1 selection, I'll show data on Grid2. Grid2 contains 4 columns and I can edit all 4 columns.

I'm retrieving nearly 240 rows of data from table for Grid2 and stored in a dataset`objPolicyDocDS`. From that `objPolicyDocDS`, I fetch particular rows (around 8 rows) by implementing search condition (based on selection on Grid1) in `objPolicyDocDS` and stored the retrieved rows in local datatable `objPolicyDocDT` and set that `objPolicyDocDT` as datasource to Grid2 and bind it.

```
DataSet objPolicyDocDS = new DataSet();
DataTable objPolicyDocDT = new DataTable();
strXML = objApplicationAdmin.GetPolicyTranSubTypes(strSQLCon);
objXMLDoc.LoadXml(strXML);
XmlReader objXMLReader = new XmlNodeReader(objXMLDoc);
objPolicySubDS.ReadXml(objXMLReader);
objPolicySubDT = objPolicySubDS.Tables.Select(<Grid1 condition>).CopyToDataTable();
spgrdPolicySubTranTypes.DataSource = objPolicySubDT;
```

My question, now I'm editing one row in Grid2 and I want it to update the new data alone in dataset only. Not to update in database. So that when I change the selection in Grid1 to some other condition and get back to old condition, the changed data will be displayed from dataset, instead of old data from database.

Also if I add new row means, how to add that too to dataset.

Is it possible to do without using looping..?

Comment: so you are loading all masterdata in DataTable1 and all child data in DataTable2 and after that you do not query the database anymore but use the records in both tables instead ?

Comment: Grid1 is from separate table, Grid2 is from separate table. I'm loading data only from Grid2 table and using only one DataTable. Grid1 PrimaryKey is linked with Grid2 as ForeginKey. Yes, after loading, I do not query the database anymore and use the DataSet only for all update and adding.

Comment: then you can try to call the AcceptChanges method from the DataTable to write the changes you have made into the DataTable. Since you are not repopulating the datatable this could work for you